# Ошибка при проверки записи БД

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Есть код PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = '$login' LIMIT 1"; 

$res = mysqli_query($mysql_con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($res); // Если занят, то придет '1', если свободен, то придет '0'
 if ($row) {
    mysqli_query($mysql_con, "INSERT INTO 'users' ('id', 'login', 'password', 'email', 'IP', 'Browser', 'Date', 'City') VALUES ('', '$login', '$password', '$email', '$ipaddress', '$browser', '$Date', '$result');");
 } else {}
```

Когда есть логин - записывает в таблицу, если его нету, то ТОЖЕ записывает в таблицу.

Comment: так неправильно делать `'$login'`, в чем проблема проверить выполнение запроса на ошибку? http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

Если поле id у вас auto_increment то:

```
INSERT INTO 'users' ('login', 'password', 'email', 'IP', 'Browser', 'Date', 'City') VALUES ('$login', '$password', '$email', '$ipaddress', '$browser', '$Date', '$result')
```

Comment: Сама проверка на наличие логина правильна ?

Comment: @VIP300100 Проверка в принципе правильна, но не безопасна. Предположим я одновременно с двух адресов посылаю запрос на регистрацию одного и того же логина. Первый скрипт выполняет проверку, записи в БД нет. Тут ОС его приостанавливает, что бы дать время другому процессу (это происходит сплошь и рядом). Второй процесс то же делает проверку и записи то же все еще нет, он вставляет запись. Тут ОС отдает управление первому потоку и он то же вставляет запись. В итоге две записи с одним логином. Единственный способ этого избежать - сделать поле login в БД уникальным.

Comment: @VIP300100 Плюс к этому производить проверку наличия одновременно со вставкой. в виде `insert ignore` или `insert ... select ... where not exists(...)`

Comment: @Mike Я пробую , и бесполезно , скрипт ваще не волнуется если ли логин в таблице или его нет , он в любом случае добавляет в таблицу

Comment: @VIP300100 проверяйте результаты запросов на ошибки, выводите отладочную информацию, что бы понимать что реально возращается. И вообще у вас условие на оборот написано, если такой есть то добавляем. Уникальность поля в таблице по крайней мере позволила бы заведомо отсечь все подобные ошибки. И еще не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст, используйте привязку переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  И еще я не понимаю как у вас insert вообще выполнятся, у вас имена колонок в обычных кавычках, MySQL должен дать на это синтаксическую ошибку.

Comment: Да вот так if (empty($row)) {

Comment: Будет он выполнятся в обычных кавычках ...у него проблема в другом. И вообще неужели нельзя сделать дебаг например $row. Че мы тут тыкаемся как котята слепые.??

Comment: для автоинкремента годится null или `''`, так что не в этом дело.